# syntax erro em sistema de login - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

ERRO: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$email' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\SUPORTE\senha.php on line 6

CÓDIGO:

```
<?php
session_start();

include("config/config.php")

    $email = $mysqli ->escape_string($_POST['email']);

    if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){

        $erro[] = "E-mail inválido.";
    }

    $sql_code = "SELECT senha, codigo FROM usuario WHERE email = '$_SESSION[email]'";
    $sql_query = $mysqli->query($sql_code) or die ($mysqli->error);
    $dado = $sql_query->fetch_assoc();
    $total = $sql_query->num_rows;

    if($total == 0)
        $erro[] = "O e-mail informado é inválido.";

    if(count($erro) ==0 && $total > 0) {


    if(isset($_POST[ok])){
        $novasenha = substr(md5(time()), 0, 6);
        $nscriptografada = md5(md5($novasenha));

          }

        if(mail($email, "Sua nova senha", "Sua nova senha: " .$novasenha)){

        $sql_code = "UPDATE usuario SET senha = '$nscriptografada' WHERE email = '$email' ";
        $sql_query = $mysqli->query($sql_code) or die($mysqli->error);

        }
      }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Erro de sintaxe, falta `;` no include

Answer (score 1):

Faltou um ponto e vírgula nesta linha:

```
include("config/config.php");
```

Tem um espaço a mais nesta linha:

```
 $email = $mysqli ->escape_string($_POST['email']);
```

O correto é:

```
 $email = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['email']);
```

Comment: Permanece com o mesmo erro amigo.

Comment: Editei a resposta

Comment: @bins o espaço nao é problema nenhum, é só o `;` mesmo. O PHP aceita espaços entre o `->` e o objeto e seus membros https://ideone.com/xY0UIA

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\SUPORTE\senha.php on line 6

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function escape_string() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\SUPORTE\senha.php:6 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\SUPORTE\senha.php on line 6

Agora apareceu mais esses dois erros...

Comment: @AbsolutnetInternet isso é falta de criar um objeto mysqli antes de usar. Note que o site não é um helpdesk e nem site de ajuda, postagens seguidas com este tipo de problema podem bloquear sua conta para postagens. Entenda melhor o site na [help]. Se for problema de código, poste sempre um [mcve], e de preferência aprenda  básico da linguagem antes, para evitar enganos como o da pergunta e do comentário que fez agora.